# Is there common template engine for html to be used in php, python and java

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

I am front end developer. I work for different platforms like php, django and java. Is there a template engine that can be used for all of these?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at Logic-less templates [Mustache](https://mustache.github.io/)!

Answer (score 1):

If you're thinking of client-side templates (HTML), I'd say most libraries and frameworks are server side-agnostic.

You might want to look at examples like:

- Angular
- Underscore
- Ember
- Knockout

They all support view templates data-bound to JavaScript objects.

So, as long as your server side app can exchange JSON with the client, it doesn't really matter which server side stack you're using.

Hope that makes sense?

Comment: I have used Angular for templating. But i had problems with including js dependency files within the templates. Is there topic for angular templating in particular.